# Can map.getBounds be executed for a different coordinate system?

Tags: leaflet

I execute the following code in my leaflet webmap

```
map.getBounds().getWest() + "&y1=" + 
map.getBounds().getSouth() + "&x2=" + 
map.getBounds().getEast() + "&y2=" + 
map.getBounds().getNorth()
```

This results in a result showing me four coordinates in the WGS84 (standard) coordinate system.

Is there any way to alter this so it will output 28992 coordinates instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that by "28992 coordinates" you're referring to the [EPSG:28992 Coordinate Reference System](https://epsg.io/28992).

The canonical way to use "non-standard" CRSs in Leaflet is to leverage [proj4leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet). *This answer assumes that you're already doing so*.

So the `getBounds()` method of `L.Map` always returns a `L.LatLngBounds` instance, which refer to unprojected WGS84 coordinates. However, we can use the [map's CRS](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-crs) to [project](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#crs-project) a `L.LatLng` into a `L.Point` with the *projected* coordinates, in the map's display CRS; e.g.

```
var map = L.map('containerId`, { crs: crsForEpsg28992 });

var foo = map.options.crs.project(L.latLng([60.3,21.1]));
var qux = map.options.crs.project(map.getCenter());
```

Because of how map projections work (they rotate and bend the coordinate spaces), and because of how [proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js) is implemented, it's not possible to project a bounding box into a bounding box. (In most cases, the projection of a bounding box would be a *curved polygon*!). This image from [an article by Gregor Aisch](https://www.vis4.net/blog/2015/01/no-more-mercator-tiles/) illustrates the issue:

[image]

We can, however, do an approximation: project the four corners of the bounding box, e.g.:

```
var mapBounds = map.getBounds();
var crs = map.options.crs;
var nw = crs.project(mapBounds.getNorthWest());   
var ne = crs.project(mapBounds.getNorthEast());
var sw = crs.project(mapBounds.getSouthWest());
var se = crs.project(mapBounds.getSouthEast());
```

We can even create a `L.Bounds` (but **not** a `L.LatLngBounds`!) from those projected coordinates; that'll be a bbox in the specified CRS that contains all corners, e.g.:

```
var bbox = L.bounds([nw, ne, sw, se]);
```

It's not gonna be perfect, but that approximation should be enough for most use cases.

See also this [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/l0NtLsIjXMItomql) (based off on one of the proj4leaflet examples), which should further illustrate the issue.